# Why is this not a comment, but an answer?

Tags: discussion, comment, flagging, answers, specific-answer

This answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1083253/1102

I flagged it as 'not an answer', as it ought to be a comment, but the flag was <strike>declined</strike> disputed. I believe there were a few delete votes on it too, not sure what happened to those.

It is fine to be skeptical about inequalities like this (even I am), but apparently this is a contest problem, so such 'answers' are unwarranted.

Even if it was not a contest problem, this is still a comment.

Why are the moderators encouraging such non-answers?

Comment: To be fair, the answer was posted without knowledge of it being a contest problem, but that is irrelevant.

Comment: Maybe you should also tag this with the tag ([meta-tag:specific-answer]); unless the answer you're linking to is supposed to serve only as an example for a discussion about general question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the disposition of the subsequent review was disputed, it means that users voted and did not come to the decision to delete. This is why your flag was disputed, not declined. Later the answer was deleted by three 20K+ users.

Comment: I see. What does disputed mean? Does it mean it could change to helpful in the future? How is it different from declined? TBH, I was too hasty. Sorry about that. Edited the question.

Comment: @Aryabhata See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141400/ and from a less technical viewpoint, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19084/

Comment: @Fundamental: Thanks. Now I am confused :-)

Comment: @Fundamental: Thanks, the second link is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

I can address part of your question.  Delete votes can only be cast by 20k users on answers when they have negative score (directly that is, not through review queue).  If there are pending delete votes, and then the question is upvoted to a nonnegative score, the pending delete votes do not show up.  After downvoting the answer I reloaded the page, and it did show 2 pending delete votes.  I cast a third.

Comment: I see, that explains that. Thanks! (and the answer is gone!).

Comment: @Aryabhata Sometimes moderators prefer the community takes care of such answers. =)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Can the community move an answer into a comment? I was under the impression only the moderators can do that. (btw, you can't defer everything to the community. In this case, the situation was clear IMO :-))

Comment: @Aryabhata I wasn't around when this happened. No, community cannot move answers to comments, but they can delete, which is sometimes better. But when moderators delete things... well. =)